# How to optimize multiple variable check

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const {
    service,
    customer,
    company,
    parking,
    aircraftType,
    aircraft,
    endPlan,
    startPlan,
    heatingPointsMasterCodes,
    lavatoryType,
    passengersCategory } = formValues;

useEffect(() => {
    customer &&
        company &&
        (parking || service === ReferenceCodesOfServicesEnum.ProvisioningMinibus) &&
        aircraftType &&
        aircraft &&
        endPlan &&
        startPlan &&
        (heatingPointsMasterCodes ||
            lavatoryType ||
            passengersCategory ||
            formValues[DocumentItemNamesEnum.WaterSystemMaintenance] ||
            service === ReferenceCodesOfServicesEnum.AircraftCooling)
        ? setDisabled(false)
        : setDisabled(true);
}, [formValues]);
```

So my question is, how to optimize or reduce variable check for true value?
First i get variables with destructing from object, then check same variables for true value.
I think i can somehow optimize this, but dont know how

Comment: That's quite the logic statement, is the purpose of e.g. `aircraftType` just to make sure it has a value? And if so, does it need to be checked in this statement? (Several values that don't sound like booleans are checked but don't appear to be used)

Answer (score 1):

In general if you have a series of `if` checks you could consider turning it into a `switch` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Since you're mostly checking to make sure things are defined, but also have some more nuanced requirements, it may be better break it up slightly:

```js
// Properties required irrespective of environment properties in DocumentItemNamesEnum or  ReferenceCodesOfServicesEnum
const requiredProperties = ["customer",
"company", "aircraftType",
"aircraft", "endPlan",
"startPlan"]

const requiredPropertiesDefined = requiredProperties.every(value => !!value)

useEffect(() => {
   if (requiredPropertiesDefined && 
       (formValues.parking || formValues.service === ReferenceCodesOfServicesEnum.ProvisioningMinibus) &&
   && (formValues.heatingPointsMasterCodes ||
  formValues.lavatoryType ||
  formValues.passengersCategory ||
  formValues[DocumentItemNamesEnum.WaterSystemMaintenance] ||
  service === ReferenceCodesOfServicesEnum.AircraftCooling) {
   setDisabled(true)
} else {
   setDisabled(false
   }
}, [formValues])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if all values of object are truthy then following code can be used.

```
Object.values(formValues).every(value => !!value)
```